# A question on probability of two related evenets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{E_1}$,$\mathcal{E_2}$ be two events such that $\mathcal{E_1}\subseteq \mathcal{E_2}$. Is it true that $Pr(\mathcal{E_1})\le Pr(\mathcal{E_2})$ ? Can anyone please justify or provide counter argument. Thanks

Comment: Note that $E_2=E_1\cup(E_2\setminus E_1)$, and that the sets on the right are disjoint.

Comment: @carmichael561 thanks

Comment: Yes, all probability measures have this property (because a probability measure is a *positive* measure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E_1 \subseteq E_2 $ implies that $E_2=E_1 \cup (E_1^c \cap E_2)$

By definition of the probability measure if A and B are disjoint then $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$. Therefore, we have
$$P(E_1) \leq P(E_1) + P(E_1^c \cap E_2) = P(E_1 \cup (E_1^c \cap E_2))=P(E_2)$$

where the first inequality is strict if $P(E_1^c \cap E_2)>0$.

Comment: $E_1 \cap E_2 = E_1$. How is the first statement true?

Comment: It is not; it is missing a complement marker. $E_1\subseteq E_2$ iff $E_1=E_1\cap E_2$.  Which implies that  $E_2=E_1\cup(E_1^\complement\cap E_2)$.

Comment: Yeah, silly me. Corrected now.